# JetBrains: How to disable "These files do not belong to the project" dialog completely?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I want to use JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA for editing files that are external to my project.  How do I permanently disable this Non-Project Files Access dialog?  Is there a relevant registry setting?

[image]

Comment: IntelliJ version?

Comment: Wow, long time passed since I last saw someone posting that legacy windows ui on SO.

Comment: Isn't it just a classic theme on Windows? I used to switch to the classic theme when PC was very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin for doing this, I also like the fact you can use Intellij as an editor with that plugin. 
[Non Project Files Unlocker](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7635?pr=idea). I'm using it with Intellij 15 and it's working fine.

But your version looks like older, I don't think, they they have some configuration for that. There's a feature request for this at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125379

Comment: Running IDEA 14.1.5 on Win7 (w/ classic theme) -- the plugin worked perfectly, thx!